# Xcode and Archiving to ipa file

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipa

I have a project in Xcode. What the app does is you can take photos and the photos are listed in a table and when you click on a cell, it will display the photo in the next page (segues to that page). When I run the program on my phone by pressing "Run" in Xcode, the photo shows up in the page after their cell is clicked. But, if I archive the project and run the ipa file on my phone, when i try to see a photo, the page is empty; the image is not displayed.

I'm running latest Xcode version.

Comment: How are you running the ipa file on the phone? Was it downloaded over the air from some service? How exactly did you get it on the phone?

Comment: Looks like an absolute path problem.

Comment: i used itunes to put the ipa on the phone. what is an absolute path problem?

Comment: PS: i use ad hoc distribution profile to make the ipa file and it installs normally on phone. it just doesn't show the picture.